# Python Socket [Errno 10049] 'The requested address is not valid in its context'

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to get a python socket code to work. The server is running fine, but the client won't bind to an IP address. Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatClient.py", line 27, in <module>
    s.bind((host, port))
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\python\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
Press any key to continue . . .
```

And here's the code...

```
import socket
import threading
import os
import time

tLock = threading.Lock()
shutdown = False

def receving(name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            tLock.acquire()
            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                print str(data)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            tLock.release()

host = '76.106.199.228'
port = 0

server = ('76.106.199.228', 5000)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.setblocking(0)

rT = threading.Thread(target=receving, args=("RecvThread",s))
rT.start()

alias = raw_input("Name: ")
message = raw_input(alias + ": ")
while message != 'q':
    if message != '':    
        s.sendto(alias + ": " + message, server)
    tLock.acquire()
    message = raw_input(alias + ": ")
    tLock.release()
    time.sleep(0.2)

shudown = True
rT.join()
s.close()
```

What's wrong with the code? I've been searching around google, this website, and a few others, but can't seem to find anything. When I try the solutions they just don't work...
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`host` needs to be a local address

```
bind(...) method of socket._socketobject instance
    bind(address)

    Bind the socket to a local address.  For IP sockets, the address is a
    pair (host, port); the host must refer to the local host. For raw packet
    sockets the address is a tuple (ifname, proto [,pkttype [,hatype]])
```

Is it possible you mean `s.connect` instead?

Comment: I tried s.connect, but it wouldn't send the messages to the server for some reason. Is there any way I could bind it or do something similar to bind but to an external address?