# server.bind(), only local ip address

Tags: python, sockets

I can't define a server with the real IP address of my computer, it gives me an error.When I do this with my local IP address it works but I want to run the client in other computer

```
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(('my_ip',9876))
server_socket.listen(1)
(client_socket,client_address)=server_socket.accept()
recived_data=client_socket.recv(999999999)
password=open(r'D:\passwords','wb')
password.write(recived_data)
client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

the client:

```
import socket
my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(('the_real_ip', 9876))
```

the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Heights/Documents/Projects/Cyber/Password_Server.py", line 4, in <module>
server_socket.bind(('my_ip',9876))
File "D:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Socket \[Errno 10049\] 'The requested address is not valid in its context'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005738/python-socket-errno-10049-the-requested-address-is-not-valid-in-its-context)

Comment: Could you explain better the problem? Because socket.bind "binds" the socket to a local address. This means that you can run the same program also on another computer. If you want to run the client, then you need to know the server IP address, but the python server does not need to know that. That's stuff for the client (where you need to use `.connect`)

Comment: I want to know how to connect to the server in my computer from client out of my LAN. so if I use the local IP in the .bind() so what addres I need to use in the .connect()

Comment: The IP address of the machine you are running the server on (and the port 9876 must be open on that machine). Suppose that your server IP address is 1.2.3.4. Then, your client (a different python script possibly) will `.connect` to the IP 1.2.3.4. If these machines are not connected, then you need to see the public ip address of the server machine (a service like http://whatismyipaddress.com/)

Comment: @Markon Did it alreay. It just cant find the server that way, it gives an 'error that show if i connect to IP that doesnt exists.
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'

Comment: Could you post both the server and client code?

Comment: @Markon Posted the client code

Comment: Without some hint at what address you are using it's hard to say for sure, but it sounds like you are behind a NAT and are trying to bind to your network's public IP?  That won't work.  You have to bind to an address on a local interface.  If you want to be able to reach that host from outside your LAN you will have to configure a NAT rule (e.g., a port forward).

Comment: @Markon I use my local IP in .bind() and my public IP in .connect()
the public IP is 83.253.240.63 and the local is 10.0.0.5

Comment: Are you able to ping at least the public IP address from the other computer?   By the way, you should use  "0.0.0.0" in the server script, (listen on every network interface)  if you want to make your host accessible from outside (not "localhost", as this can only communicate with clients on the same host).

Comment: its weird the ping isn't working

Comment: It's not weird. Your host is not publicly accessible. Can you change firewall rules on the server machine? Because that's what you need to do.

Comment: turned off the firewall, the ping is now working but stil the client cant find the host. the ping isn't working from he server pc to the client pc, but I turned off the firewall.

Comment: Wait, is the client able to contact/ping the server? This is what matters most. What does it mean that "the client cannot find the host"?

Comment: @Markon the server cant be pinged. I canceled the firewall but it is still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0',9876))` and `server_socket.bind(('',9876))`

Check this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

To connect from outside your LAN, you have to connect to the router of that LAN using the 'outside IP' and make let the router formward the connection to the 'local IP'.